# Rollback All DB Commits in Nested Transactions in Spring

Tags: java, spring, nested, rollback, spring-transactions

I have the following service layout of nested transactions:

```
@Component
public class Main implements RPCInterface {

  @Autowired
  private ServiceA serviceA;

  @Autowired
  private ServiceB serviceB;

  @Autowired
  private ServiceC serviceC;

  @Override
  @Transactional (value="txManager", propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor={ExceptionOne.class, ExceptionTwo.class, ExceptionThree.class})
  public void outerMethod() throws ExceptionO {

    try {
      serviceA.methodA();
      serviceB.methodB();
      serviceC.methodC();

    } catch (ExceptionOne e) {
      throw new ExceptionO(e.getMessage, e);
    } catch (ExceptionTwo e) {
      throw new ExceptionO(e.getMessage, e);
    } catch (ExceptionThree e) {
      throw new ExceptionO(e.getMessage, e);
    }
  }
}

@Service
public class ServiceA implements SA {

  @Autowired
  private ServiceA1 serviceA1;

  @Override
  public void methodA() {
    serviceA1.methodA1();
  }
}

@Service
public class ServiceA1 implements SA1 {
  @Autowired
  private ServiceDBTable1 serviceDBTable1;

  @Autowired
  private ServiceA1A serviceA1A;

  @Transactional
  @Override
  public void methodA1() {
    serviceDBTable4.callToMapper4();
    serviceA1A.methodA1A();
  }
}

@Service
@Transactional (value="txManager", propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
public class ServiceA1A implements SA1A {

  @Autowired
  private ServiceDBTable2 serviceDBTable2;

  @Override
  public void methodA1A() {
    serviceDBTable1.callToMapper1();
  }
}

@Service
public class ServiceB implements SB {

  @Autowired
  private ServiceDBTable3 serviceDBTable3;

  @Override
  @Transactional (value="txManager", propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
  public void methodB() {
    serviceDBTable3.callToMapper3();
  }
}

@Service
public class ServiceC implements SC {

  @Override
  public void methodC() throws ExceptionThree {
    // code that throws ExceptionThree
  }
}
```

I need to make all the DB calls within `ServiceA` and `ServiceB` nested calls to rollback when `ServiceC#methodC()` throws an exception (or any of them for that matter that throws an exception -- `ServiceA` or `ServiceB`).

I tried to make `Main#outerMethod` transactional with `REQUIRED` propagation, but it seems like the database commits are not being rolled back. I have even specified the specific classes with `rollbackFor` but the commits persist. Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: Why don't you put the innerMethodThree  into the same transaction as innerMethod_1a and 2a?

Comment: @Simon How do I accomplish that? `innerMethodThree` must be called after 1) and 2).

Comment: set the @Transactional on the outerMethod and do not require new for 1a and 2a

Comment: @Simon I updated the question with a more concrete example. I removed `@Transactional` from `ServiceA1.methodA1()` and `ServiceB.methodB()` and placed it on `Main#outerMethod()`, but the rollbacks are not occurring.

Comment: try remove the try catch, let the service throw the ExceptionOne, Two, Three, or throw those exceptions in the catch, you are not rolling back the change for ExceptionO

Comment: @Simon `Main` is actually part of an RPC handler that must throw `ExceptionO`. For that reason, all business exceptions must be caught and rethrown by `outerMethod` as we cannot add new exceptions to it (`@Override` on the interface. I forgot to add that to `Main` class definition).

Comment: I mean you can add the ExceptionO in the rollbackFor clause

Comment: @Simon I see. You are right, the `outerMethod` does not rollback for `ExceptionO`. Regardless, I think from the design point of view, I am better to move all the micro-service calls to a centralized upper-level service method as I suspect `Main` might be replaced with *REST* calls at some point in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I did to make it work was to migrate `ServiceB.methodB()` and `ServiceC.methodC()` calls to `ServiceA.methodA()`, and make `methodA()` `@Transactional` while throwing all my exceptions from `methodA()` and rollback based on those three exceptions (my logic actually allowed me to do that):

```
@Component
public class Main implements RPCInterface {

  @Autowired
  private ServiceA serviceA;

  @Override
  public void outerMethod() throws ExceptionO {

    try {
      serviceA.methodA();

    } catch (ExceptionOne e) {
      throw new ExceptionO(e.getMessage, e);
    } catch (ExceptionTwo e) {
      throw new ExceptionO(e.getMessage, e);
    } catch (ExceptionThree e) {
      throw new ExceptionO(e.getMessage, e);
    }
  }
}

@Service
public class ServiceA implements SA {

  @Autowired
  private ServiceA1 serviceA1;

  @Autowired
  private ServiceB serviceB;

  @Autowired
  private ServiceC serviceC;

  @Override
  @Transactional (value="txManager", propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor={ExceptionOne.class, ExceptionTwo.class, ExceptionThree.class})
  public void methodA() throw ExceptionOne, ExceptionTwo, ExceptionThree {
    serviceA1.methodA1();
    serviceB.methodB();
    serviceC.methodC();
  }
}

@Service
public class ServiceA1 implements SA1 {
  @Autowired
  private ServiceDBTable1 serviceDBTable1;

  @Autowired
  private ServiceA1A serviceA1A;

  @Transactional
  @Override
  public void methodA1() {
    serviceDBTable4.callToMapper4();
    serviceA1A.methodA1A();
  }
}

@Service
@Transactional (value="txManager", propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
public class ServiceA1A implements SA1A {

  @Autowired
  private ServiceDBTable2 serviceDBTable2;

  @Override
  public void methodA1A() {
    serviceDBTable1.callToMapper1();
  }
}

@Service
public class ServiceB implements SB {

  @Autowired
  private ServiceDBTable3 serviceDBTable3;

  @Override
  @Transactional (value="txManager", propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
  public void methodB() {
    serviceDBTable3.callToMapper3();
  }
}

@Service
public class ServiceC implements SC {

  @Override
  public void methodC() throws ExceptionThree {
    // code that throws ExceptionThree
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no code presented it is hard to know for sure.
However, transactions only work when methods are public. Private methods are not proxied and hence transaction support for them is not there.

Read through [Declarative Transations - Spring Docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.6.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#transaction-declarative-annotations) for more details.

Please post code if you still are struggling for getting better help.

Comment: The inner methods are all service calls (one service/object, calling another service/object), so they have to be public. The question was whether the above configuration should or shouldn't work. The amount of scattered code makes it hard to post the actual code, hence the condensed version above.